# internal track link with AdMob

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Does AdMob find apps published on internal track? It is not clear if they do.

My first Android app is published on an internal track since Nov 17th. The callback function onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo from Consent SDK returns "Could not parse Event FE preflight response." and I believe this is because the app was not linked yet. Shall I wait for AdMob to discover my app, if ever, or is there another reason to this error?

Answer (score 0):

This normally isn't because the app isn't linked. It is normally because you have set the publisher ids wrong. Do you have the right publisher ids in your app?

[github support question](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android/issues/11)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have had an experienced developer look at my code, AdMob Console and Google Play Console and he found everything in order. Since yesterday, the entire code has been sent to AdMob SDK team for review. Currently I am waiting for their response.

Comment: @DaniDobre Did you fix this problem? Having the same one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405294/android-google-admob-could-not-parse-event-fe-preflight-response-but-i-have-cor

Comment: @DaniDobre did you find a solution?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler did you find a solution?

Comment: @atreeon I didn't re-read this question, however in my comment Apr 24 at 16:29 it seems that I have posted myself a StackOverflow question about the same problem ; I have indeed solved this problem. My question and my own answer are available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405294/android-google-admob-could-not-parse-event-fe-preflight-response-but-i-have-cor . If I've understood your poblem, it will solve it, indeed. Don't hesitate to upvote these both questions and my answer if you find it useful.