# Android Google AdMob: Could not parse Event FE preflight response BUT I have correctly indicated the Publisher ID

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-admob

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(that);
                String[] publisherIds = {"pub-XYZYXYZYXYZYXYZXY"};
                consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
                        Consent consent = new Consent();
                        if(!ConsentInformation.getInstance(that).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()) {
                            consentCallback(that, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                        } else {
                            if(consentStatus == ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {
                                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                                extras.putString("npa", "1");
                                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras).build();
                                consentCallback(that, adRequest);
                            } else if(consentStatus == ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED) {
                                consentCallback(that, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                            } else if(consentStatus == ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN) {
                                consent.collectConsent(that, miscellaneous, new ConsentInterface() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void callbackConsentInterface(AdRequest adRequest) {
                                        consentCallback(that, adRequest);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

So as you can see, I've correctly indicated my Pub ID (as highlighted in this similar question: [Android - ConsentInformation - Could not parse Event FE preflight response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798529/android-consentinformation-could-not-parse-event-fe-preflight-response)).

However I still have this error:

> W/System.err: Could not parse Event FE preflight response.

What could I do to fix this bug?

I precise that I didn't enter my bank account information in Google AdMob, and I can't do it to test for firm and technical reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem simply by strictly following those three steps I've imaginated. I've tested almost all combinations of them: if one of these steps isn't followed, you will get this "Could not parse Event". Otherwise, you won't get this error.

1. Follow these docs: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent + https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob ("Get started for Android") + https://developers.google.com/admob ("Android setup")
2. Be sure to specify your ***Publisher*** ID in the Publisher IDs array for the Consent API (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2784578)
3. Important: fill-in your payments informations in your Google AdMob account (https://apps.admob.com/v2/payments/settings) (not speaking about your credit card or any other payment method, but about your living coordinates)
4. Wait <= 24 hours
5. Following the above docs, create your AdMob "app", etc.
6. Be sure to have selected some providers in "Blocking Controls > EU Consent > Select ad technology providers" (https://apps.admob.com/v2/pubcontrols/eu-user-consent) (normally it's impossible to not have selected something)
7. [Not-Tested but found on the Internet] In your App-Level Gradle file, be sure to have:

   minifyEnabled false

   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Then it should work.

Comment: In my case, point 7 of your list solves my problem, but that is not the solution I want. So I will disable personalized ads until minify can be reactivated. Thank you for your answer, I have been searching for a really long time to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error may appear if your AdMob account isn't yet approved. Wait until the "Under Review" message disappear and try again.