# Consent form is not loading when App was downloaded from Play Store

Tags: android, gdprconsentform

I have integrated the consent form in my app.
If I run the app in debug mode it will be displayed.
If I build and install a signed APK, the consent form will be displayed.

If I download the app from the Play Store, I get no error message and the following code is reached. The  code inside `consentInformation.request...`won't be reached.

```
   consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this);
   String[] publisherIds = {"pub-xxx"};
   consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
      @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
        **//*seems to be not reached**
        ...
        }
   }
```

the consent is therefore not displayed - But only when downloading from Play Store.

Is there a bug or missed I something?

Thanks
GGK

Comment: So I guess it only works in debug mode not production? Can you try a release APK and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: Not exactly..it runs in debug. Iit also works when I build an APK and install that on devices. It doesn't run, when the app was downloaded from Play Store

Answer (score 1):

for whatever reason:

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

solved the problem. more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405294/android-google-admob-could-not-parse-event-fe-preflight-response-but-i-have-cor?answertab=votes#tab-top) AnswerID 1